# Firebase Authentication in Unity / iOS App without email and password

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to authenticate a user in Firebase by ONLY using a user-generated signature which is stored in Firestore? In other words, is there a way to generate a unique user ID associated with the signature but without having to have the user create an account with email and password?